# sails-inverse-model authentification error on postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I tried sails-inverse-model on a several postgres DBs on a local VM.

sails-inverse-model -u myPostgresUser -p myPasswd -d myDBname -t pg -m -v -c

And I systematically have an authentification error authentification by Passwd failed for user « myPostgresUser»

Any idea what's wrong or what I dis wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct?

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue:

```
C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails-inverse-model\node_modules\pg-json-schema-export
```

In that folder open `package.json` and check the dependencies

I changed `"pg.js"` to [`"pg": "^7.4.1"`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) as `pg.js` is deprecated. Save the file and in the same folder and run `npm update`